# Scale Img to specific point

Tags: c#, image-processing

How do I scale an image to a specific point?

I can use the `Matrix` object for example to rotate at a specific point:

```
var matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.RotateAt(33, new PointF(100, 200));
```

But with scale I cannot set this point:

```
matrix.Scale(0.5, 0.5);
```

I need something like this (not existing) method overload:

```
matrix.ScaleAt(0.5, 0.5, new PointF(100, 200));
```

(I need the effect like when you click on a point in an image it zooms in to this point)

How can I do that?

Comment: actually the ScaleAt method exists in .NET 3 and onwards, which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method your looking for exists in .NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.scaleat.aspx